# FXML window without native window frame

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, fxml

I am trying to display a screen without its native frame.
I created an small application using JavaFx and their design in FXML, When the application launch at that time the first screen display but it take the operating system default frame and button and I want a screen without native frame, Like this screen will display same in MAC and Windows.

Please help me if anyone having the solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

See the javadocs for `Stage` for more options.

Comment: It is working fine, I have used all the properties of initStyle(), like StageStyle.UNDECORATED